# Structure a stylesheet to manage skins or themes

Tags: css, less

How can I structure a `CSS` or `LESS` file to manage skins or themes?

ex: using `LESS` vars to stock colors, or link to img patterns, and if I change this file the look of the site changes... but I don't know really how to proceed, I mean the better way?

Colors vars (dark/middle_dark/basic/middle_light/light) and do the same for all basic colors

```
/*neuter*/
@g_d_neuter: #3c3c3c; /*etc...*/

/*blue*/
@g_d_blue: #2D4B55; /*etc...*/
```

But for CSS classes I don't know how to structure the thing. Could I do like below:

```
.g_plans {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: @g_l_neuter;
    border: solid 1px @g_ml_neuter;
 }
.g_titles {}
.g_texts {margin-bottom: 10px;}
.g_items {background-color: @g_l_neuter;}
.g_labels {}
```

etc...

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for. Could you provide an example for what you mean with "structure"?

Comment: Quite vague. An example would help us to answer, and also show us that you've already actually done something...

Comment: @icedwater i just edit the question take a look...

Answer (score 1):

A first idea would be to use different CSS files, and then write the `<link>` that references them using some JavaScript or PHP variable:

```
<link href = "<?php echo $_request['theme_name'] ?>" rel = "stylesheet" />
```

A variation on this theme should cover it.

Comment: thanks, but the problem not how to apply but how to sructure the CSS file, i just edit the question take a look...

Comment: Ah, finally I get it. Sorry. >_<

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, you would not create a CSS file that contained elements from different themes.

Keeping themes in separate CSS files makes the themes isolated and simplifies maintenance and retesting.

That is unless it is typical that the document will regularly switch themes whilst it is being viewed.  Even if this is the scenario, there's no reason why different themes cannot be implemented with different CSS files.

(Regardless whether or not the CSS files were produced statically, or dynamically using a preprocessor like LESS)

Answer (score 1):

### I Think You Need to Abstract A Bit More

**File #1: All Possible Color, Img, Etc. Definitions**

In this file you define all your possible colors, images to be used, etc.

```
/*neuter*/
@g_d_neuter: #3c3c3c; /*etc...*/

/*blue*/
@g_d_blue: #2D4B55; /*etc...*/
```

**File #2: Theme Definitions File (here for your "neutral" theme perhaps)**

You include the color definitions (File #1) into this file so it can define more "generic" variable names using the colors, images, etc. from File #1.

```
@backgroundColor: @g_d_neuter; /*etc...*/
@borderColor: @someColorValueForNeutralThemeBordersDefinedInFirstFile;
```

**File #3: CSS Build File**

To build the theme, import that theme file (File #2) into this file (or before this file) and then use those "generic" variables to define your actual classes, mixins, etc. This way, every theme is defining the same set of necessary variables for the output CSS.

```
.g_plans {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: @backgroundColor;
    border: solid 1px @borderColor;
 }
.g_titles {}
.g_texts {margin-bottom: 10px;}
.g_items {background-color: @backgroundColor;}
.g_labels {}
```

**Summary**

Essentially, File #1 is your styling, File #3 is your sight structure and application of styles, and File #2 is the interface that changes the specific color variables from File #1 into generic references that allows File #3 to not have to change its variable definitions from theme to theme.